# Seeking a combinatorial proof $\sum\limits _{k=0}^n (n-2k)^2\binom{n}{k}=n\times 2^n$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

Q: Seeking a combinatorial proof $(\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!}
)$

$$\sum _{k=0}^n (n-2 k)^2 \binom{n}{k}=n\times
 2^n$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider all subsets of a set of $n$ elements, along with their complements; count $+1$ for each ordered pair of (possibly identical) elements that are in the same set (i.e. both in the subset or both in its complement) and $-1$ for each ordered pair of elements that aren't. Then for a subset of size $k$, of which there are $\binom nk$, the sum is $((n-k) - (k))^2=(n-2k)^2$. A pair of different elements doesn't contribute to the sum over all subsets, since they are in the same set just as often as they are in different sets. A pair of identical elements contributes $+1$ for each of the $2^n$ subsets, and there are $n$ such pairs.

Comment: Please explain more clear. Thank you so much -- "count $+1$ for each ordered pair of (possibly identical) elements that are in the same set (i.e. both in the subset or both in its complement) and $-1$ for each ordered pair of elements that aren't."--

Comment: @Young: I'll rephrase it, but I'm not sure that will help -- if not, you may have to ask more specifically. For each of the subsets $S$ of a set of $n$ elements, and for each ordered pair $(i,j)$ (e.g. if the set is $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, ordered pairs would be $(1,1)$, $(1,2)$, $(2,1)$, etc.) add up a $+1$ if $i\in S$ and $j\in S$ or $i\not\in S$ and $j\not\in S$, and a $-1$ otherwise. I hope that's clearer?

Comment: Thank you. one more explain  --the sum is $((n-k) - (k))^2=(n-2k)^2$--

Comment: Understand exactly. Thank you.!!

Comment: I don't understand it at all, could you explain it differently. I don't know how do you come up with sum $(n-2n)^2$ and  A pair of different elements don't contribute to the sum over all subsets since they are in the same set just as often as they are in different sets. A pair of identical elements contribute +1 for each of the 2n subsets, and there are n such pairs. I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: @TomášMacháček The sum for a subset of size $k$ is $((n-k)-(k))^2=(n-2k)^2$, not $(n-2n)^2$ (which would just be $n^2$). WLOG, assume $n-k\ge k$. Pick $k$ among the $n-k$ elements in the complement. The contributions from these $k$ elements cancel the contributions where these elements are replaced by the $k$ elements in the set. There remain $(n-k)-(k)=n-2k$ elements, and the contributions from the ordered pairs containing only these elements are all $+1$, so they sum to $(n-2k)^2$.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a proof using generating functions. (What could be more combinatorial?)

Let $s_n$ be the sum in question and $f$ the exponential generating function of the sequence of $s_n$'s. Algebra-wise, $(n-2k)^2=(n-k)^2-2k(n-k)+k^2$, so $s_n=2\sum_k\binom nk(k^2-k(n-k))$. Then, the product rule for exponential generating functions applies. The egf of the sequence $\langle n:n\ge0\rangle$ is $xe^x$ and the egf of $\langle n^2:n\ge0\rangle$ is $x(x+1)e^x$. Two applications of the product rule give $f(x)=2(x(x+1)e^x\cdot e^x-(xe^x)^2)$. This simplifies to $f(x)=2xe^{2x}$. Extracting the coefficient of $x^n$, we get $s_n=n!2[x^n]xe^{2x}=n2^n$.

Comment: That is not a combinatorial argument, I’m afraid. The term has a well-understood meaning.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Sure, I am taking the liberal interpretation that combinatorics is synonymous with generating functions, but I understand (and mainly agree with) your point of view.