# Finite series with a suprising result.

Tags: sequences-and-series

There is a finite series:

\begin{equation}
   \mathscr{S} = \sum_{n=0}^{m} {m \choose n}(m-2n)^2
\end{equation}

If I divide $\mathscr{S}$ by $2^{m}$ I get m. Could anyone explain it to me?

Comment: Or how do you prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{m} {m \choose n}(m-2n)^2$ is equal to $2^m \cdot m$.

Comment: Induction?.....

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1468485/42969